# Ocultar funciones lógica en una celda en Excel con PHPExcel

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Buenas estoy registrando datos en una tabla de Excel que tiene tres campos y en ella me va guardando en MySql con PHPExcel, donde una celda (el campo 'valor') hay una función lógica que es la siguiente: (=SI([@valor]>="5";"Rojo";"Verde")) obviamente en la celda no muestra esta función al presionar la tecla Enter pero cuando lo guardo en MySql me registra con toda esa linea de funciones osea en vez el resultado (Rojo) me registra como (=SI([@valor]>="5";"Rojo";"Verde")) en el campo 'valor' de MySql, quisiera saber como 'oculto' esa función y que me muestre solamente el resultado de la función Verdadero y Falso. Comparto el archivo .php:

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';
include ("Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");
$html="<table border='1'>";
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('estacion.xlsm');

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet)
{
    $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
    for ($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++)
    {
        $html.="<tr>";
        $fecha_hora = mysqli_real_escape_string($obj_conexion, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue());
        $valor= mysqli_real_escape_string($obj_conexion, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue());
        $estado = mysqli_real_escape_string($obj_conexion, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue());
        $sql = "INSERT INTO datos (fecha_hora, valor, estado) VALUES ('".$fecha_hora."','".$valor."',".$estado.")";
        mysqli_query($obj_conexion, $sql);
        $html.= '<td>'.$fecha_hora.'</td>';
        $html.= '<td>'.$valor.'</td>';
        $html.= '<td>'.$estado.'</td>';
        $html.= "</tr>";
    }

}
```

Comment: Intenta utilizando la función `getCalculatedValue()` en lugar de utilizar `getValue()`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su comentario intente con esa función que usted escribió pero daba error sin embargo he investigado un poco por lo que parece que la librería PHPExcel no lo aceptaba  (creo que es por la versión) así que encontré que la función correcta es `getOldCalculatedValue()`.de todos modo gracias. Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He solucionado el problema gracias al comentario de @Marcos, lo único que hay que cambiar es `getOldCalculatedValue()` en vez de `getValue()` así mismo devuelve una fórmula ya calculada.

Quedaría así en esta linea de código:

```
$valor= mysqli_real_escape_string($obj_conexion, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getOldCalculatedValue());
```